# Content service error in Cd_core logs

Tags: content-manager, discovery

I'm getting the below error in the Content Service, any idea why this is coming?

> ERROR JMSCacheChannelConnector - JMS Exception occurred during reception of event. Attempting setting up JMS connectivity again
>   javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from bytes. Reason: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.tridion.cache.CacheEvent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8109545960597551825, local class serialVersionUID = 1252887747292650827
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:198) ~[activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector.handleJmsMessage(JMSCacheChannelConnector.java:219) ~[cd_cache-8.1.1-1012.jar:8.1.1-1012]
>       at com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector$2.onMessage(JMSCacheChannelConnector.java:84) [cd_cache-8.1.1-1012.jar:8.1.1-1012]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1393) [activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131) [activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202) [activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133) [activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48) [activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_92]
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.tridion.cache.CacheEvent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8109545960597551825, local class serialVersionUID = 1252887747292650827
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
>       at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:191) ~[activemq-client-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
>       ... 10 common frames omitted

Comment: I haven an idea, it happens because something is wrong ;o). It would be good if your **edit** your question and provide a bit more details, see https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for some details on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely reason is that you have version mismatch between the JAR's in your deployer service and content service.

This can happen when you apply hotfixes to a service. When faced with a similar issue in the past I've made sure to grab a hotfix version that includes both services to make sure they are aligned.